# How do I teleport 2 blocks in front of an armor stand with a custom name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As you can see the question is in the title. I've tried:

```
/tp @p @e[type=ArmorStand,name=the armor stand name] ~ ~ ~2
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What command have you used to summon the armor stand?

Comment: /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"whatever"}

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing two commands.

1. /tp @p @e[type=armor_stand,name=**Name**]
2. /tp @p ~ ~ ~-2

Answer (score 0):

If you teleport a player to a different entity like the example you used, you cannot include (relative) coordinates. It's or to a different entity, or to coordinates. You can solve your problem using a /execute

```
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=NAME] ~ ~ ~2 teleport @p ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: This does nothing. I have tested it and it will teleport the player to its current position.

Comment: This won't work with `/tp`, because `/tp`'s teleport location is relative to the target (in which the player will be teleported to themselves, and the origin modification done with `/execute` only changes who the target can be rather than where they are teleported). You'd want to use `/teleport` instead, which would be relative to the executor (and then the origin change from `/execute` can work effectively). Prior to `/teleport`'s introduction, you would have to use two `/tp` commands: one to teleport target to target, and another to teleport target 2 blocks away.